# Return documents that meet a Sub-query Result Set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to solve a problem that in Sql Server would require a common table expression or subquery.

I have a collection named Invoice_Details. Each document has an InvoiceID, CustomerID, TransactionDate and TransactionAmount field.

What I am looking to do is get back all of the document that when the TransactionAmount is aggregated, does not equal zero.

I am doing the grouping as follows:

```
   db.Invoice_Details.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { InvoiceID: "$InvoiceID"},
           Balance: { $sum: "$TransactionAmount"}
         }
     },
     { $match: { Balance: { $ne: 0 } } }
   ]
)
```

and this yields

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "InvoiceID" : "234904"
    },
    "Balance" : 182.67
}
```

....  hundreds of additional documents which is great.

What I want to do now is get all of the invoice_details documents that were returned in the the aggregate.

In Sql Server, I would rejoin the results of the common table expression/subquery, but I'm not sure how (if?) I can do this mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could do a [`"$lookup"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) based on the `"InvoiceID"` and immediately [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the results, just in case we are talking about large enough document results which could actually breach the BSON Limit;

```
db.Invoice_Details.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$InvoiceID",
    "balance": { "$sum": "$TransactionAmount" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "balance": { "$ne": 0 } } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Invoice_Details",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "InvoiceID",
    "as": "details"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$details" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$details" } }
])
```

Ideally you would [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) here to simply promote the field with all results into the document root. Otherwise use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and name all the fields if your MongoDB version is less than 3.4 and lacks the pipeline stage:

```
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$details._id",
    "InvoiceID": "$details.InvoiceID",
    "CustomerID": "$details.CustomerID",
    "TransactionDate": "$details.TransactionDate",
    "TransactionAmount": "$details.TransactionAmount"
  }}
```

But essentially doing the [`"$lookup"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) here is effectively the "sub-query" and join condition on the `"InvoiceID"`, it's just that MongoDB presents it in a different order. So "sequentially" as "aggregate first" then join.

Comment: So this worked, but even in a collection with only 529442 documents it's timing out. The first part (prior to the lookup) runs in about 5 seconds. Am I taking the wrong approach here completely, or s this the sort of thing that is understandably slow?

Comment: @MillinMo Add a `$sort` stage on the `InvoiceID` at the start. In the real world you would likely have a `$match` for a date range first really. Most importantly **Do not run in Robo3T**. It's really broken software and not MongoDB supported. Use the mongo shell as it just works. Is it the wrong approach to mimic SQL? Almost certainly, but without re-engineering this is essentially what you have